# ASP.NET MVC 5: How to avoid hidden form field manipulation during model binding?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-injection

I am working on a tutorial from the Microsoft website with the end result like this image:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5/_static/image4.png

The price textbox in the View is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlbumToEdit.Price, "Price", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AlbumToEdit.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlbumToEdit.Price)
    </div>
</div>
```

Which renders as:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="AlbumToEdit_Price" name="AlbumToEdit.Price" type="text" value="9.99">
```

If I inspect the HTML via DevTools and add the below:

`<input id="AlbumToEdit_Price" name="AlbumToEdit.Price" type="hidden" value="33.33">`

And click the Save button to save the album details, the binding process is taking the 33.33 in consideration, regardless what I insert in the Price textbox, probably because both `<input>` tags share the same id and name.

How can I avoid this?

Controller code follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(AlbumToEditViewModel postedViewModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(postedViewModel.AlbumToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    AlbumToEditViewModel albumToEditViewModel = new AlbumToEditViewModel
    {
        AlbumToEdit = postedViewModel.AlbumToEdit,
        Artists = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", postedViewModel.AlbumToEdit.ArtistId),
        Genres = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name", postedViewModel.AlbumToEdit.GenreId)
    };

    return View(albumToEditViewModel);

}
```

Comment: Simple put: don't trust user input.

Comment: Why are you using a hidden if you have an input?

Comment: I am not, I added it via DevTools to simulate a behaviour from users with malicious intent, of course this is a very basic example but I believe this could be very dangerous to allow.

Comment: It's dangerous to trust user input. If there's a value that you don't want them to be in control of, then don't accept values from them. Why would you let the user tell you what the price should be?